# Which different between two regex patterns in nginx conf

Tags: regex, nginx

Which different between two regex patterns?

```
location ~ /.myfolder
```

and

```
location ~ /.myfolder$
```

First pattern works in my two servers.
But in the third server in dont work and I need to use second pattern (the configuration in conf file the same).

And I don't understand what is the different between patterns?

P.S1. In two servers root folder (for nginx) located on /var/www

P.S2. But for third server root folder (for nginx) located on /root/www

Maybe it related on permissions, because nginx works as www-data

Comment: `$` is an end of line anchor, which means that the URI must end with `/.myfolder`. The first pattern will match any URI that contains `/.myfolder`, at the beginning, at the end, or somewhere in-between.

Comment: @RichardSmith files, folders, configuration the same for 3 server. But it don't work only on the third server